# could not connect to the internet

Tags: maps, geocoding, cllocationmanager, 3g, reverse-geocoding

I'm using CLLocationManager to determine the current location and i'm using maps.google.com for reverse geocoding. Whenever I switch from wifi to 3g network and try to run my app which gets the current location, the map application launches with a message 'could not connect to the internet' even though i have a good 3g signal.

This happens everytime. Anyone seen this type of behavior before ? Any ways to work around it besides preventing the app in the background? I am releasing the locationmgr object so there is no cache.

Comment: do u have a intermediate proxy ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I'm just using the iOS API directly and once i get the current location i launch the maps application.  I tried killing the app manually on the iphone and tried the test again ... i got the same cannot connect to internet error